# почему выдает два раза ноль?

Tags: c++, указатели, память

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
/* run this program using the
   console pauser or add your
   own getch, system("pause")
   or input loop */

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int *i = new int;
    for (*i = 0; *i < 5; *i++)
    {
        cout << *i <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Простой ответ: приоритет ++ больше приоритета  *

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что вы таки увеличиваете указатель `i`

```
*i++
```

а не значение, которое лежит по этому адресу

```
(*i)++
```

В результате вы просто роетесь в **чужой** памяти в поисках чего-то, что будет не меньше 5...

Answer (score 4):

Для начала начнем с этого:

```
int *i = new int;
```

В данной строчке вы выделяете некоторый объем памяти, равный *sizeof(int)* и присваиваете указатель на выделенную вами память переменной i, все это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
            i // адрес памяти вымышленный

            ↓

| ... | 0x00AFFA00 | ... |
```

Далее:

```
for (*i = 0; *i < 5; *i++)
{
    cout << *i << endl;
}
```

В данном отрывке кода, на первой итерации вы "разыменовываете" указатель, т.е. берете адрес выделенной вами памяти и инициализируете ее нулем. После чего вы сравниваете содержимое выделенного участка памяти и если он меньше пяти... Вот тут и происходит самое интересное. Вместо того чтобы инкрементировать значение, хранящееся по этому адресу вы инкрементируете указатель. Теперь более нагляднее:

```
                          i // адрес памяти вымышленный

                          ↓

0 итерация -  | ... | 0x00AFFA00 |  ... |

                                       i // адрес памяти вымышленный

                                       ↓

1 итерация -  | ... | 0x00AFFA00 | 0x00AFFA04 | ... |

                                                    i // адрес памяти вымышленный

                                                    ↓

2 итерация -  | ... | 0x00AFFA00 | 0x00AFFA04 | 0x00AFFA08 | ... |


...
```

Сначала расскажу об основных проблемах, которые появляются из-за данного действия, а потом о возможно решении:

1. **Утечка памяти:** Вы просто потеряли указатель на выделенную вами память и освободить ее у вас теперь не получится.
2. **Неопределенное поведение:** Вы вторгались(в данном случае хорошо, что просто ее читали) в чужую память, которая вам не принадлежит.

Возможное решение:
Как сказал @Harry, необходимо просто заменить *i++ на (*i)++. Так как при разборе выражения компилятором, операция *i++ будет разобрана как *(p++), а не как (*p)++, из-за приоритета операций в языке С++. Подробнее о приоритете операций можете прочитать [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Надеюсь мой ответ оказался вам полезным... Также советую вам разобраться в концепции указателей, она присутствует и в других языках, но в С++ она выражена явно. Вот пару хороших статей для начального уровня: [одна](http://scrutator.me/post/2016/03/30/pointers_demystified_p3.aspx), [другая](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/12/30/pointers_demystified_p2.aspx) и  [третья](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/11/26/pointers_demystified_p1.aspx).